# How I can do this effect? css jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, parallax

I dont know how to do this effect
http://www.putput.dk/
[image]

I want to do exactly same that I am showing in the image

Comment: Perhaps view source?

Comment: Google 'paralax'.

Comment: You mean the parallax effect...?

Comment: I think it is not paralax

Comment: Stackoverflow is neither a *"how to"* tutorial service or a free code writing service or a resource recommendation service

Answer (score 0):

If you open the dev console `We built this site with the help of Manipulator, an extremely flexible and performance optimised JavaScript library. Check out parentnode.dk if you want to know more.`

Check out http://parentnode.dk/ for their Manipulator javascript library. It might be what you're looking for. It's unclear from your question which effect you're looking for. Perhaps if you describe the part you're referencing it may help.